# Julia Studios does not deindent end statements

Tags: julia, julia-studio

I wanted to try Julia and thought it would be nice to start of using Julia Studios. For some reason it seems the editor does not indent loops and end-statements correctly. I tried looking in preferences but couldn't find anything to help, neither when googeling. Anyone else experienced this problem?

I'm on a OSX 10.7+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia Studio has been unsupported and deprecated for a long time (years?), which seems to be pretty clearly indicated on the Forio website. You could try [Juno](http://junolab.org/) or I just use Sublime Text and the Julia REPL in the terminal.